# Unity tmp fonts breaking when game is built from command line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a makefile to autmote the building and uploading of my unity game

```
unity: unity_win unity_mac unity_tux
unity_win:
    $(UNITY_LOCATION) -quit -batchmode -projectpath ./project -buildWindowsPlayer .$(BUILD_DIR)/win/game.exe -logFile $(BUILD_LOG)/mac.log
unity_mac:
    $(UNITY_LOCATION) -quit -batchmode -projectpath ./project -buildOSXUniversalPlayer .$(BUILD_DIR)/mac/game.app -logFile $(BUILD_LOG)/win.log
unity_tux:
    $(UNITY_LOCATION) -quit -batchmode -projectpath ./project -buildLinux64Player .$(BUILD_DIR)/tux/game -logFile $(BUILD_LOG)/tux.log
```

when I build my game directly from the editor (unity -> build settings -> build) everything works as expected, but when using the executable produced from this script, any font in a scene that is addressable is not rendered (blank on mac, purple rectangles on win / linux). this issue started happeing after i intergrated addressables.

The font used in non-addressable and addressable scenes is identical (default text mesh pro font).

Comment: Are you building the Addressable content at the same time or have you built it and not changed anything before the player build?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Addressables is configured to be built whenever the player is built